# i have used laravel blade template make layout but doent work

Tags: laravel

**Template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>App Name @yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body>
    @section('content')
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**View:**

```
@section('content')

@if(session('message'))
<p>{{session('message')}}</p>
@endif
@foreach ($posts as $post)
<h2><a href="{{url('/posts/show/'.$post->id)}}"> {{$post->title}}</a></h2>
<p>{{$post->body}}</p>
<a href="{{url('/posts/'.$post->id.'/edit')}}">Edit</a>
<a href="{{url('/posts/'.$post->id.'/delete')}}">Delete</a>
@endforeach
@endsection
```

I have used this code and get white screen how to solve this problem
make layout folder and layout file get only white screen no any error and output

Comment: You should use `@yield('content')` in the body. You also need to make sure errors are shown because this should clearly show an error and not a white screen

Answer (score 0):

MASTE PAGE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
        @yield('metas')
        @yield('head')
        @yield('style')
    </head>
    <title>@yield('title')</title>

    <body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">
        @yield('body')
    </body>

    <footer>
        @yield('footer')
        @yield('script_whole')
    </footer>
</html>
```

CHILD PAGES:

```
@extends('path.to.master_page')

@section('head') 
    //head elemetns here
@endsection

@section('style') 
    //style here
@endsection

@section('title', 'my_title')

@section('content')
    //content elemetns here
@endsection

@section('footer')
    //footer elemetns here
@endsection

@section('script_whole')
    //scripts here
@endsection
```

and now every page that `extends` from MASTER_page, so should use `@section`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
@section('content');
```

in main blade file use

```
@yield('content');
```